# Integer expression expected (Bash)

Tags: linux, string, bash, if-statement, int

I'm trying to create a simple script that checks if the CPU Usage is at a certain level.  I have a Raspberry Pi for this project.

The only issue I have currently is that I have the variable `CPU` which is the CPU usage, when the script runs, I get the error

```
line 25: [: 4.8: integer expression expected
```

I'm not sure why bash returns this if BASH really doesn't care about int, String, etc. like JAVA does. Found that out [here](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/converting-string-to-integer-in-bash-608444/).

Also, I have the if statement: `if $CPU -gt 1` only for testing (it's supposed to return true right now)

```
red='\e[0;31m'
yellow='\e[1;33m'
NC='\e[0m' # No Color
echo -e "${NC}Starting Server!${NC}"
echo -e "${red}Errors in red!${NC}"
echo -e "${yellow}Info in yellow!${NC}"
sleep 1
echo -e "\n\n"
##CPU USAGE STUFF
echo -e "${yellow}Current CPU Usage:"
CPU=$(top -bn1 | grep "Cpu(s)" | \
           sed "s/.*, *\([0-9.]*\)%* id.*/\1/" | \
           awk '{print 100 - $1""}')
echo $CPU %
echo -e "${NC}**********${NC}"
cd /root/mc_server/
sleep 1


##CPU USAGE LOOP CHECKER
while :
do
        sleep 5
        echo $CPU
        if [ $CPU -gt 1 ]
        then
        echo -e "${red}ALERT! CPU Usage is TOO HIGH!${red}"
        fi

done
##


##java -Xmx400M -jar bukkit.jar -o true
```

Comment: integer means integer. If you pass bash a value like 4.8 then it starts wondering if it needs to look for an exponent value, ie. 4.800889e27, and that would be a lot of work ;-). Just round your 4.8 value or truncate it and then you'll have an integer value that will work. `case $CPU in *\.* ) CPU=${CPU%%.*} ;; esac` might help. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter thanks, I'll go ahead and try it

Comment: @Olivr3000 as shelter says, simply take the whole-number from `$CPU`. The most efficient way is to remove everything up to and including the decimal beginning at the right with substring extraction. `CPU=${CPU%.*}`  `%%` works, the only difference being it say remove all occurrences of `.` beginning at the right, compared to `%` which is `first occurrence`.

Comment: @shellter Yeah, you're both right :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that 4.8 is an non-integer value.

You can use bc to deal with non-integer values like so:

```
if [[ $(echo "$CPU > 1" | bc -l) -eq 1 ]];
```

it will return boolean expressions as either 1 for true or 0 for false.